# Does Kubernetes POD have namespace and cgroup associated with it?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, docker-container, cgroups, linux-namespaces

Docker Containers have cgroups and namespaces associated with them, whether they are running in a pod or vm or host machine.
Similarly, does a Kubernetes Pod's have namespaces and cgroups associated with them, or it's just the containers within the pod have these(cgroup & namespace) associations. If they do, how can I find this info from the host?

Comment: Not sure about cgroup but kubernetes pods have namespaces. You can check is using `kubectl describe pods <name_of_pod>`. To get pods, run, `kubectl get pods`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are the container in a kubernetes pod part of same cgroup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62716970/are-the-container-in-a-kubernetes-pod-part-of-same-cgroup)

Comment: @mWatney, this is about POD not the containers in the pod. So that other Q&A is different and does not answer this Q.

Comment: I don't get your point. Every pod is a container or a set of containers and the answer is explain how things relate. If your question is if on K8S there is something similar to cgroup the answer is no, the closest is namespaces.

Comment: Regarding your new question, please post it as a new question. StackOverflow is one post per question.

Comment: @mWatney, If the questions are related, I don't think its a problem to piece them together... next regarding the main question.   you said: `Every pod is a container or a set of containers`.  I don't think a POD is same as a container... if you still think so.. can you provide any refs. The second part - you are more or less right: pod is a collection of set of containers.

Comment: From the doc [What is a Pod?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#what-is-a-pod) we have, "is a group of one or more containers". Regarding your exec question, have your checked kubectl exec?

Comment: Please can you reconsider the downvote? As you can see by the comment in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62874800/is-it-possible-to-exec-in-to-a-k8s-pod-the-same-way-we-exec-in-to-a-docker-conta#comment111186155_62874800), my statements are correct. I updated my answer adding the infromation about the concept of a Pod.

Comment: For those of you who got here wondering if pod IPC namespaces are always unique (even if the container / pod / etc is being ran as root), the answer is yes, each pod gets its own IPC namespace. You can, e.g., create a message queue with the name `/pickles` in 8 different pods and each pod would see its own queue named `/pickles` and writing to one would not write to the others. Also, the IPC namespace given to the pod is not the system IPC namespace, either.

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#what-is-a-pod) we can read:

"A Pod (as in a pod of whales or pea pod) is a group of one or more containers"

This makes us understand that for every pod we have one or more containers and a cgroup associated to it.

The following answer demonstrates that.

---

Posting this answer as Community Wiki as it is a copy/paste from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62727007/12153576).

## Cgroups

Container in a pod share part of cgroup hierarchy but each container get's it's own cgroup. We can try this out and verify ourself.

1. Start a multi container pod.

```
# cat mc2.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: two-containers
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: container1
    image: ubuntu
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]

  - name: container2
    image: ubuntu
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
```

```
# kubectl apply -f mc2.yaml
pod/two-containers created
```

2. Find the process cgroups on the host machine

```
# ps -ax | grep while | grep -v grep
19653 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/bash -c -- while true; do sleep 30; done;
19768 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/bash -c -- while true; do sleep 30; done;
```

```
# cat /proc/19653/cgroup
12:hugetlb:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
11:memory:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
10:perf_event:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
9:freezer:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
8:cpuset:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
7:net_cls,net_prio:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
6:cpu,cpuacct:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
5:blkio:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
4:pids:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
3:devices:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
2:rdma:/
1:name=systemd:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
0::/
```

```
# cat /proc/19768/cgroup
12:hugetlb:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/e10fa18a63cc26de27f3f79f46631cd814efa3ef7c2f5ace4b84cf5abce89765
11:memory:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/e10fa18a63cc26de27f3f79f46631cd814efa3ef7c2f5ace4b84cf5abce89765
10:perf_event:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/e10fa18a63cc26de27f3f79f46631cd814efa3ef7c2f5ace4b84cf5abce89765
9:freezer:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/e10fa18a63cc26de27f3f79f46631cd814efa3ef7c2f5ace4b84cf5abce89765
8:cpuset:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/e10fa18a63cc26de27f3f79f46631cd814efa3ef7c2f5ace4b84cf5abce89765
7:net_cls,net_prio:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/e10fa18a63cc26de27f3f79f46631cd814efa3ef7c2f5ace4b84cf5abce89765
6:cpu,cpuacct:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/e10fa18a63cc26de27f3f79f46631cd814efa3ef7c2f5ace4b84cf5abce89765
5:blkio:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/e10fa18a63cc26de27f3f79f46631cd814efa3ef7c2f5ace4b84cf5abce89765
4:pids:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/e10fa18a63cc26de27f3f79f46631cd814efa3ef7c2f5ace4b84cf5abce89765
3:devices:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/e10fa18a63cc26de27f3f79f46631cd814efa3ef7c2f5ace4b84cf5abce89765
2:rdma:/
1:name=systemd:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/e10fa18a63cc26de27f3f79f46631cd814efa3ef7c2f5ace4b84cf5abce89765
0::/
```

As you can see the containers in the pods share the cgroup hierarchy until `/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011` and then they get their own cgroup. ([These containers are under `besteffort` cgroup because we have not specified the resource requests](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/#qos-classes))

You can also find the cgroups of the container by logging into the container and viewing /proc/self/cgroup file. (This may not work in recent versions of kubernetes if cgroup namespace is enabled)

```
# kubectl exec -it two-containers -c container2 bash
# root@two-containers:# cat /proc/self/cgroup
12:hugetlb:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
11:memory:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
10:perf_event:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
9:freezer:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
8:cpuset:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
7:net_cls,net_prio:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
6:cpu,cpuacct:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
5:blkio:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
4:pids:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
3:devices:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
2:rdma:/
1:name=systemd:/kubepods/besteffort/poda9c80282-3f6b-4d5b-84d5-a137a6668011/ed89697807a981b82f6245ac3a13be232c1e13435d52bc3f53060d61babe1997
0::/
```

---

## Namespaces

Containers in pod also share network and IPC namespaces by default.

```
# cd /proc/19768/ns/
# /proc/19768/ns# ls -lrt
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:41 uts -> uts:[4026536153]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:41 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:41 pid_for_children -> pid:[4026536154]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:41 pid -> pid:[4026536154]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:41 net -> net:[4026536052]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:41 mnt -> mnt:[4026536152]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:41 ipc -> ipc:[4026536049]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:41 cgroup -> cgroup:[4026531835]
```

```
# cd /proc/19653/ns
# /proc/19653/ns# ls -lrt
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:42 uts -> uts:[4026536150]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:42 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:42 pid_for_children -> pid:[4026536151]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:42 pid -> pid:[4026536151]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:42 net -> net:[4026536052]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:42 mnt -> mnt:[4026536149]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:42 ipc -> ipc:[4026536049]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 01:42 cgroup -> cgroup:[4026531835]
```

As you can see the containers share the network and IPC namespaces. You can also make the container share pid namespace using `shareProcessNamespace` field in the pod spec.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace

---

> cgroup:[4026531835] is same for both the containers. Is this(cgroup namespace) different from the cgroups they (containers) are part of.

cgroups limits the resources(cpu, memory etc) which a process(or group of processes) can use.

namespaces isolate and limit the visibility a process(or a group of processes) has over system resources like network, process trees etc. There are different namespace groups like network, IPC etc. One of such namespace is cgroup namespace. Using cgroup namespace you can limit the visibility of other cgroups from a process(or group of processes)

cgroup namespace virtualises the view of a process's cgroups. Currently if you try `cat /proc/self/cgroup` from within the container, you would be able to see the full cgroup hierarchy starting from the global cgroup root. This can be avoided using cgroup namespaces and is available from [kubernetes v1.19](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/1370). [Docker also supports this from version 20.03](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/38377). When cgroup namespace is used while creating the container, you would see the cgroup root as `/` inside the container instead of seeing the global cgroups hierarchy.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroup_namespaces.7.html

Answer (score 6):

[group of whales is called a pod](https://www.google.com/search?q=group+of+whales&oq=group+of+whales&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j0l6.4403j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Consider a pod of two humpback whales. One whale is grey in color and other is blue.

What is the color of the pod? The question doesn't make much sense as color is the property of each individual whale.

What is the species of the pod? Well you can say it is a humbpack pod as all the whales in the pod are humpback whales but again species has nothing to do with the pod. It is the individual whale that belongs to that species.

---

Similarly group of containers is a pod in Kubernetes. Properties like cgroups and namespaces are applicable for containers. Sometimes it is convenient to talk about some properties at pod level like network namespace or IPC namespace because all the containers in the pod usually share the same network and IPC namespaces. But inherently they are container properties.