# Is it possible to exec in to a K8s pod the same way we exec in to a docker containers or containers running inside of a pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, namespaces, kubernetes-pod, nsenter

Is it possible to `exec` in to a K8s pod the same way we `exec` into docker containers or containers running inside of a pod?p

**Edit -**
This question not about `exec`ing into a container in a pod. This is about the pod itself. Might be it's not possible but that is what the question is about. So stop marking it duplicate with - [Can we exec into container in a POD in K8S?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54981900/can-we-exec-into-container-in-a-pod-in-k8s)

Comment: A pod is nothing but a group of one or more containers.Can you elaborate what you mean by exec into a pod?

Comment: so, the answer is no.. that's what I am looking at. A POD is a collection of one or more containers, it does not have an image or os associated with it... so it's not possible to exec using kubectl...

Comment: but if pod has it's own process, which i think it does, then it will be possible to do `nsenter` to the process (if it has it's own namespace). I am not sure if a pod has it's own logical NS.

Answer (score 4):

Pod is a group of containers and is a logical concept. So you can not really exec into a pod. All you can do is exec into one of the containers in the pod.

`kubectl exec` command might make you think that you are execingy into a pod but you actually exec into the container.This command works only if its a single container pod.If there are multiple container in the pod i.e it's a multi container pod then you need to choose a container explicitly using `-c` option.

Here is the output of `kubectl exec -h` which mentions about containers too.

```
Execute a command in a container.

Examples:
  # Get output from running 'date' command from pod mypod, using the first container by default
  kubectl exec mypod -- date
  
  # Get output from running 'date' command in ruby-container from pod mypod
  kubectl exec mypod -c ruby-container -- date
  
  # Switch to raw terminal mode, sends stdin to 'bash' in ruby-container from pod mypod
  # and sends stdout/stderr from 'bash' back to the client
  kubectl exec mypod -c ruby-container -i -t -- bash -il
```

A `pause` container gets created before any other actual container of the pod gets created.Responsibility of the `pause` container is to create the linux namespaces which will be shared among the other containers of the pod.

There is no way to exec into that pause container using `kubectl exec` but you can exec into it using `docker exec`.

Comment: does the pod have it's own NS different from the Host and the containers.  ???

Comment: By default pod has separate namespace than the host..but you can manipulate it to share certain things from the host..for example 'hostNetwork:true' will make the container inside the pod share same network namespace as the host

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using kubectl exec command we can shell into a running container/pod

```
controlplane $ kubectl run --image=nginx web --restart=Never
pod/web created
controlplane $ kubectl get po
NAME   READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
web    0/1     ContainerCreating   0          4s
controlplane $ kubectl exec -it web -- /bin/bash
root@web:/# ls
bin   dev                  docker-entrypoint.sh  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  docker-entrypoint.d  etc                   lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
```

Answer (score 1):

A pod is an abstract entity that wraps your container. When you exec to a pod via kubectl exec -it   you are actually executing the wrapper command for your container. Also there is nothing for you to exec in to Pod.